# Post to an API every after 15 minutes

Tags: android, timer, http-post

I want to know how could I setup my application to update its details via API post every after 15 minutes. Right now, I knos how to use get and use a thread in order to create a loader for it while accessing the API.

Here's how I do it:

```
private int authenticateLogin()
  {
      EditText user = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.username));
      EditText pass = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.password));

      StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

      StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

      String username = user.getText().toString(), password = pass.getText().toString();

      String URL = "MyUrl";
      String authData = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);
      httpget.setHeader("Authorization", authData); 
      HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            StatusLine sl = response.getStatusLine();
            int statCode = sl.getStatusCode();
            if (statCode == 200) {
                String entityStringDrivers = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this,DriverLogin.class);
                i.putExtra("stringDrivers", entityStringDrivers);
                startActivity(i);
                return 100;
            }
            else
            {
                user.setText("");
                pass.setText("");
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Unauthorized Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                return 100;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 100;
        }
        finally {
        }

  }
```

I want to to know how should I do it when posting and do it in background. I don't know where to start specially with the every 15 minutes POST. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: This will eat battery. A nicer way could be to use GCM to tell you application when something interesting has happened and it needs to update itself. https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can check this out , and use Intent Services to run in the back ground.

[android timer](http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2007/11/stitch-in-time.html), For intent servicse check it out [Intent Services](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Implementing_an_Android_Started_Service_%E2%80%93_A_Worked_Example)

Answer (score 0):

Use a handler for the timer as follows:
In the snippet call `startTimeReqTask()` to start your timer.

```
private Handler m_handler = new Handler();
....

   Runnable m_handlerTask = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, 900000); // 15 minutes
            new authenticateLoginTask().execute(); // POST (your asynctask)
        }
    };


    private void startTimeReqTask() // start timer
    {
        m_handlerTask.run(); 
    }

    private void stopTimeReqTask() // stop time
    {
        m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask);
    }
```

And use `AsyncTask` authenticateLoginTask for doing it background.

Comment: Will this work even if the application is currently not on top of the device? Or some activites is being done to the device?

Comment: Yup! I am using this code on my download service.My app checks the server every 10 min to see if new contents are available. This should work for you, I think.

Comment: How about if the screen is lock? Cause it seems that when the screen is locked, the processing stops. I included a notification tone to check every 1 minute. When the screen is locked, it won't play the tone.

Comment: Also got this error. Cannot refer to a non-final variable m_handlerTask inside an inner class defined in a different method

Comment: Why using an inner class? Anyway, you can put final at the beginning if thats you want. private final Handler m_handler = new Handler();

Comment: By the way, it is supposed to work even if the screen is locked!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this background, create a Service and start it in your main activity's onCreate or some BroadcastReceiver

eg:( You need to add try-catch or other sort of protective code)

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //Use intent to pass your username and password here
        //start a PostThread here.      
    }

    private class PostThread extends Thread {
        private static final int INTERVAL = 15 * 60 * 1000L;
        private boolean canceled = false;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!canceled) {
                Post();
                Thread.sleep(INTERVAL); // or you can use a Timer to trigger this 
            }            
        }
        public void interrupt() { canceled = true; super.interrupt();} 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // call your api  method here
                }
            });
        }
    }, 0, /*here define your internal*/);

// when you no longer required this api call just call "cancel" method of timer
```

Comment: Does this work even when the app is hidden? or another app is opened? or even if the screen is locked? Because, I tried a similar code just like this and it seems to stop when the screen is locked. Not exactly when the screen is locked, but at some point it will stop.